# Can't push to the same array twice

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have a simple object

```
var errors = {};
```

and I am pushing dynamically new values into it like this:

```js
function getNameById(id){
    return usersArray.find(item => item.id === id).name;
}

var usersArray = [
 {"id":"135","name":"Jenny"},
                    {"id":"162","name":"Kelly"}
                 ];
$("#submit").click(function (e) {           
    var errors = {};
    $(".validation").each(function(){
       var worker_id = $(this).attr('id').replace(/[^\d]/g, '');
       var w_name = getNameById(worker_id);
       errors[w_name] = [];

       if ( $(this).val() == "" ) {
           errors[w_name].push( $(this).attr('id').replace(/[^a-zA-Z]/g, '') + " must be filled!");
           //errors[w_name].push("second number must be smaller than first");
       }
       if ( $(this).attr('id') == "second-"+worker_id  && ($(this).val() < $('#first-'+worker_id+'').val())) {
         errors[w_name].push("second number must be smaller than first");
       }     
    });
    
    console.log(errors);
    e.preventDefault();
    e.stopPropagation();

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<form method="post">
  First<input id="first-135" class="validation" name="first" type="text" value="5"><br>
  Second<input id="second-135" class="validation" name="second" type="text" value="8"><br>
  Signature<input id="signature-135" class="validation" name="signature" type="text"><br>
<input id="submit" type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

And first time in first IF condition it pushes and all is fine, but in second IF it doesn't push and i don't get any error messages. And I have the same line right after the first push that is commented and if I comment it out it gets pushed like the first one.

I have created a snippet on [FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/3707tyc8/29/) so please go to inspect and open console and try to submit and you will see there is only one insertion in errors array.

Why is the second one not pushed to array?

Comment: Always a bad idea to use less-than and greater-than comparisons for string vlaues like `.val()`, unless you want to compare alphabetically. For example, `"5000" < "7"` evaluates to `true`.

Comment: It doesn't matter what they are *supposed* to be. `.val()` is a string, always. If you want to compare two dates, then you have to compare them **as** dates, not as strings like you're doing now.

Comment: `var d1 = Date.parse($(this).val()); var d2 = Date.parse($('#first-'+worker_id+'').val()); if (d1 < d2) { //do stuff }`

Comment: @lewis4u: Nice one on doing a snippet. The reason you don't see anything in the array is that you're misusing arrays. The Stack Snippet console just shows *array entries*, but your `errors` array doesn't have any. It does have named properties (which aren't array entries). `errors` should be initialized with `{}` (object), not `[]` (array); on an ES2015 JavaScript engine you might want `Map` instead. (The browser console -- which is still there even with snippets -- shows the full object, including the `Jenny` property; it's just the SS console that's more simple-minded.)

Comment: Thank you very much, i have fixed it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've been mistaken in the declaration of  `errors[w_name] = [];` every iteration you overwrite it

so thz following will fixe your problem:

replace  `errors[w_name] = [];` by   `if(!errors[w_name]) errors[w_name] = [];`

here is a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/bRIMOs/3707tyc8/31/)

Comment: In wihch case  please ?

Comment: but ,Ithing you were wrong in the implementation you wrote : `second number must be smaller than first` and in the code make the inverse --> `$(this).val() < $('#first-'+worker_id+'').val())` rather then using `>` see the [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/bRIMOs/3707tyc8/31/)

Comment: I will test as soon as I get home , actually on road :)

Comment: It works, it was my mistake. This is the solution `if(!errors[w_name]) errors[w_name] = [];` instead of `errors[w_name] = [];` it gets overwritten and that is why it didn't work.

Comment: Great ,thumbs up :)

Answer (score 2):

The problem is here:

```
if ( ... ($(this).val() < $('#first-'+worker_id+'').val()))
```

`.val()` evaluates to a *string*, and any time you use a relative operator like `<` or `>` on strings, it compares them *alphabetically*. This is probably causing some unexpected results, returning `true` when you expect `false`, and vice-versa.

Because you mentioned these are supposed to be dates, you'll need to convert them to date objects using `Date.parse()` - this of course assuming they're in a proper date format that JS can parse:

```
var d1 = Date.parse($(this).val());
var d2 = Date.parse($('#first-'+worker_id+'').val());

if (d1 < d2) {
   //first date is earlier than second date
}
```

Comment: Glad to hear! Was this in fact the cause of the issue?

Comment: The reason I asked is because I was surprised you accepted my answer so quickly, being that I agree with some of the other answers - your implementation of the loop is a bit wacky. I'll look into it some more.

Comment: Unfortunately I can't, no time. Though I'd suggest removing the check from my answer, as it didn't completely resolve your issue.

Comment: the accepted answer is working. that was actually my problem!